# how to set the minimum C++-standard without forcing a downgrade?

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I have a C++-project that doesn't use any "modern" C++ features by itself (you probably can still compile it with MSVC6).

However, it uses a couple of (optional) libraries, one of which requires at least C++11.

Only recently I discovered, that building the project on macOS with clang++-9.0.0 would fail to use the library (that was detected in the configure-step, so the build succeeded eventually; just without that library...), simply because the compiler would default to **C++98**. (wtf??)

A simple fix for the problem is just to pass `-std=c++11`.

However, passing `-std=c++11` to the compiler will force the standard to C++11, even if the default standard was something higher (e.g. C++14), eventually downgrading code-paths to legacy/compat versions.

Also, i might have another optional dependency that *requires* a newer standard.

Since I would like to keep compability (with older compilers) at a maximum and at the same time support all my optional dependencies, i wonder:

*Is it possible to request a minumum standard-version from the compiler, possibly forcing an upgrade of the standard, but **never a downgrade**?

Something like `-min-std=c++11` or `-std>=c++11`...

Comment: C++ is not entirely 100% backwards compatible with earlier versions. So it's safer to specify the version your code actually uses, not to try to force a higher version on code that may not like it.

Comment: well, but *sometimes* it is.... the problem being, that my code is C++98, but an included header of one of the dependencies requires C++11...